Trying to build a file sharing website from scratch in JS
So I’m new to programming, getting grasp of html css and js still workin Progress. How do I intuitively figure out how to build a file share website, is it something you look at diffrent documentation? How do you know what words to look for? It like shooting in the dark,
Trying to read docs but idk where to start

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
